# Issue Cycling through Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to Cycle through my data I'm getting back from an API Call. If I use dummy data in an array, it will cycle fine. But once I attempt to place my api data in its place, it just shows all the items at once instead of cycling one at a time. I `console.log(items.length)` and get `1` which tells me that this is an array of an object and is just reading it as a whole. Could use some help getting this displaying one item at a time instead of the whole thing at once.

**API Call(Title.js):**

```
import { Component, React } from "react";
//import TitleCycle from '../components/TitleCycle';

let headers = {
  "QB-Realm-Hostname": "XXXXXXXXXX.quickbase.com",
  "User-Agent": "FileService_Integration_V2.1",
  "Authorization": "QB-USER-TOKEN XXXXXXX_XXXX_XXXXXXXX",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
};

class Title extends Component {
    state = {
      data: null
    };
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = () => {
    let body = {"from":"bpz99ram7","select":[3,6,40],"where": "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}","sortBy":[{"fieldId":6,"order":"ASC"}],"groupBy":[{"fieldId":40,"grouping":"equal-values"}],"options":{"skip":0,"top":0,"compareWithAppLocalTime":false}};

    fetch("https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ data }));
  };

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    if (data === null) return "Loading Job Data...";

    return (
      <div className="Title">
        {Object.keys(data["data"]).map(item => (
          <div key={item}>
            {data["data"][item][6].value}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Title;
```

**TitleCycle.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import Title from "./header/Title";

const items = [
  // {name: "Job Name One"}, {name: "Job Name Two"}, {name: "Job Name Three"},
   <Title/>       //Problem is here because this is showing as an object of objects? Needs to be an array
];

console.log(items.length)
//console.log(items.length) this shows 1, meaning only one item with multiple objects...
export default function TitleCycle() {
  const [titleData, setTitleData] = React.useState(items[0]);
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

  // Set Timer and Interval based on Index
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(
      () => setIndex((i) => (i + 1) % items.length),
      2000 // 2 seconds.
    ); 
    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
  }, []);

  // Set TitleData with Index
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTitleData(items[index]);
  }, [index]);

  return (
    <div className="TitleCycle">
      <h3>{titleData}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "3": {
        "value": 177
      },
      "6": {
        "value": "2220 Three Kings "
      },
      "40": {
        "value": "In Progress"
      }
    },
    {
      "3": {
        "value": 302
      },
      "6": {
        "value": "529 Woodsview"
      },
      "40": {
        "value": "In Progress"
      }
    },
    {
      "3": {
        "value": 9
      },
      "6": {
        "value": "7948 Red Tail"
      },
      "40": {
        "value": "In Progress"
      }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

The issue is that it is reading as 1 item, but because my api is reading as an object of objects, instead of an array. I'm ultimately trying to send this data over to TitleCycle.js to cycle through and display each one in a duration at a time.

**UPDATE:** My issue seems to be how I'm attempting to send `<Title />` from Title.js to TitleCycle.js to use the API Response as the items array in question.

I'm trying to do the API call in one file, send that array over to TitleCycle.js to cycle based on duration.

Comment: Your `items` array has only 1 element in it. What are you expecting? Can you clarify further what the issue is?

Comment: To be able to convert this as "an object of objects" of sorts, to an array that I can display one item at a time. Right now, I'm thinking it's reading it as an object of ```data```. (updated to show api response)

Comment: What part of the data do you want rendered?

Comment: ID "6" which is the Job Name value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've an array of objects then you need to pick out the object properties you want rendered.

For a given element object:

```
{
  "3": {
    "value": 177
  },
  "6": {
    "value": "2220 Three Kings "
  },
  "40": {
    "value": "In Progress"
  }
}
```

Select one of the `"3"|"6"|"40"` property's `value` property to render:

```
function TitleCycle() {
  const [titleData, setTitleData] = React.useState(items[0]);
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

  // Set Timer and Interval based on Index
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(
      () => setIndex((i) => (i + 1) % items.length),
      2000 // 2 seconds.
    ); 
    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
  }, []);

  // Set TitleData with Index
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTitleData(items[index]);
  }, [index]);

  return (
    <div className="TitleCycle">
      <h3>{titleData["6"].value}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You could also save the extra state and render cycle by consuming the updated index instead.

```
function TitleCycle() {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

  // Set Timer and Interval based on Index
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(
      () => setIndex((i) => (i + 1) % items.length),
      2000 // 2 seconds.
    ); 
    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="TitleCycle">
      <h3>{items[index]["6"].value}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Demo

[image: Edit issue-cycling-through-array]

### Update

It seems you need to render the `TitleCycle` component in `Title` instead of the divs with the titles.

```
class Title extends Component {
  state = {
    data: null,
  };
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = () => {
    let body = {"from":"bpz99ram7","select":[3,6,40],"where": "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}","sortBy":[{"fieldId":6,"order":"ASC"}],"groupBy":[{"fieldId":40,"grouping":"equal-values"}],"options":{"skip":0,"top":0,"compareWithAppLocalTime":false}};

    fetch("https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(({ data }) => this.setState({ data })); // <-- destructure data from response
  };

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    if (data === null) return "Loading Job Data...";

    return (
      <div className="Title">
        <Titlecycle data={data} /> // <-- pass data
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Access the passed `data` prop and render. Conditionally render the titles only if the `data` array has a truthy length (i.e. non-zero length).

```
function TitleCycle({ data }) { // <-- destructure data
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

  // Set Timer and Interval based on Index
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setInterval(
      () => setIndex((i) => (i + 1) % data.length),
      2000 // 2 seconds.
    ); 
    return () => clearInterval(timerId);
  }, [data]); // <-- handle if data array prop changes

  return data.length ? (
    <div className="TitleCycle">
      <h3>{data[index]["6"].value}</h3>
    </div>
  ) : null;
}
```

### Demo

[image: Edit issue-cycling-through-array (forked)]

Comment: What would you recommend if I keep getting ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined```

Comment: @AlexB801 Works in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-cycling-through-array-3huvw). Can you provide a codesandbox with the code you are running that isn't working? If it's not working then my guess is that your `items` array or "data" isn't what you think it is. Can you provide the *actual* `items` array you are attempting to render from?

Comment: I just came to that conclusion as well actually. lol I'm thinking it isn't the code itself, but rather, how I'm sending this data from one component over to the TitleCycle.js. If I create an array then it works as expected, but not when I'm doing it on two different files.

Comment: @AlexB801 Oh, you're trying to send `items` as props to `TitleCycle`? Can you update your question to include this detail or how you're trying to do it?

Comment: Yes, I'm already getting the Data Job Names on my Title.js with the API call, so I'm attempting to just send ```<Title />``` over as the items array, which appears to be the problem?

Comment: So you're setting your items as an array of the titles, How would I go about doing that for my Title.js file since that is already making the API call?

Comment: @AlexB801 No, passing the entire `data` state. I renamed the prop to `data` to alleviate any confusion. The "title" is accessed from the passed data when rendering in `TitleCycle` component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233521/discussion-between-alexb801-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should or *can* pass the prop as `key`.

Try doing your `Array.map` with two parameters `(item, index)`

Then make the `key={index}` and pass the item as a prop to the actual component not a div:

```
       <TitleCycle item={item} ....
```

**EDIT**

Additionally you can destructure the props object that gets passed to TitleCycle:

```
export default const TitleCycle = ({ item }) => {

    //Now item === the individual top-level object for each component

}
```